# function taking a list as argument doesn't working as expected

Tags: python, list

```
def example(b): 
    b = b + ['z']


b = [1,2,3]

example(b)
```

Howcome after I execute the above example, the value of `b` still remains

```
[1,2,3]
```

expected output

```
[1,2,3,'z']
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are creating a new list and reassigning it to the variable `b` inside the function.

If you instead used `.append()` you would get the results you expect.

```
def example(b):
    b.append('z')

b = [1,2,3]
example(b)
```

I'd suggest you look at [python variable scoping for more details](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html).